# Word Wrap doesn't work for nbsp and hypen inside text area?

Tags: css

Word Wrap inside text area doesn't work correctly for hypens and &nbsp. Is there any solution to make this work.

Here's my basic code:

```
  <textarea id="rteSample" rows="10" cols="30" style="width: 100%; height: 440px">
The&nbsp;labrum&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;hip&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;dense&nbsp;fibrocartilagenous&nbsp;structure,&nbsp;much&nbsp;like&nbsp;the&nbsp;meniscus&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;knee.&nbsp;It&nbsp;is&nbsp;situated&nbsp;inside&nbsp;the&nbsp;hip&nbsp;joint-capsule&nbsp;and&nbsp;attached&nbsp;non-magnet&nbsp;the&nbsp;pelvic&nbsp;side&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;hip&nbsp;joint.&nbsp;It&nbsp;effectively&nbsp;increases&nbsp;the&nbsp;depth&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;acetabulum&nbsp;and&nbsp;provides&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;smooth&nbsp;transition&nbsp;from&nbsp;the&nbsp;acetabulum&nbsp;to&nbsp;the&nbsp;capsule.&nbsp;A&nbsp;labral&nbsp;tear&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;disruption&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;continuity&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;labrum.&nbsp;It&nbsp;may&nbsp;occur&nbsp;at&nbsp;the&nbsp;pelvis&nbsp;labra-margin&nbsp;or&nbsp;within&nbsp;the&nbsp;substance&nbsp;of&nbsp;the&nbsp;labrum.
```

Can anyone suggest your idea on this ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards,
Keerthana.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work* exactly? I see no difference -> https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/aLoxr9sa/

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you have described is expected, since `&nbsp;` stands for [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Try replacing them with regular spaces.